# SQL select from Table2 if it has a value, else from Table1

Tags: sql, select, join

I have two tables with the following data:

`Table1`:

```
PRODUCT | PRICE | NEWPRICE
```

`Table2`:

```
PRODUCT | PRICE | NEWPRICE
```

`Table1` is complete. `Table2` has been created to update `Table1`. `Table1` contains data from last year, while `Table2` is up to date. But `Table2` only contains `PRODUCT`'s which have a `NEWPRICE` this year.

Now what I try to do is:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.PRODUCT, Table1.PRICE, 
    **(IF Table2.NEWPRICE -> select this, ELSE Table1.NEWPRICE)**
```

Is there any way to do this? Maybe with some kind of `JOIN`?

PS: I know that the tables were not created wisely, but I have to work with them now, because I have to continue the work of someone else >.<

Comment: `set NEWPRICE = case when t2.newprice is not null then t2.newprice else t1.newprice end`

Comment: Does `table2` have any new products in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.PRODUCT, Table1.PRICE, COALESCE(Table2.NEWPRICE, Table1.NEWPRICE) AS "New Price"
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Product = Table2.Product
```

The `left join` will take all rows from `Table1` and the matching rows from `Table2` and if there is no matching row from `Table2` then the `Table2.NEWPRICE` will be NULL and the `COALESCE` will get the `Table1.NEWPRICE` value.

This assumes that all products exists in Table1. If that isn't the case you can build a source of all products with a union of the two tables and use that as the left side for two left joins like this:

```
select 
  all_products.product, 
  Table1.PRICE, 
  coalesce(Table2.Newprice, Table1.Newprice) AS "New Price"
from (select product from table1 union all select product from table2) all_products
left join Table1 on all_products.product = Table1.product
left join Table2 on all_products.product = Table2.product
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but the NEWPRICE column has no name now. Any way to define one? :) Edit: You just edited this. Thank you!