# Update sqlite table with non-null values from another table

Tags: database, sqlite, join, select, left-join

I have two sqlite tables, both with the same column layout. I would like to merge the two tables (or update table 1), taking values from table 2 if they are not null, otherwise, taking them from table 1. Is there a better way of doing this this short of an `UPDATE` with multiple `case` clauses (similar to the approach in [SQLITE UPDATE field IF NULL from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840729))? The tables have a large number of columns which would make such a statement quite long.

table 1

```
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
| id    | col1  | col2   | .. | col100 |
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
| 2346a | apple | red    |    | WA     |
| d27d7 | pear  | green  |    | VA     |
| 568ba | lemon | yellow |    | CA     |
| 9896f | grape | purple |    | CA     |
| 1b7da | peach | pink   |    | CA     |
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
```

table 2

```
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
| id    | col1  | col2   | .. | col100 |
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
| 2346a | null  | green  |    | null   |
| 1b7da | null  | null   |    | GA     |
| 9896f | plum  | null   |    | null   |
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
```

desired result

```
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
| id    | col1  | col2   | .. | col100 |
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
| 2346a | apple | green  |    | WA     |
| d27d7 | pear  | green  |    | VA     |
| 568ba | lemon | yellow |    | CA     |
| 9896f | plum  | purple |    | CA     |
| 1b7da | peach | pink   |    | GA     |
|-------+-------+--------+----+--------|
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL select from Table2 if it has a value, else from Table1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238960/sql-select-from-table2-if-it-has-a-value-else-from-table1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bring `table2` with a `left join` and prioritize non-`null` values from `table2` using `coalesce()`:

```
select
    t1.id,
    coalesce(t2.col1, t1.col1) col1,
    coalesce(t2.col2, t1.col2) col2,
    ...
    coalesce(t2.col100, t1.col100) col100
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Is there a way to get around specifying all 100 coalesce statements since the tables have the same column names? Or possibly a way to have sqlite generate them from the table schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ROW VALUES`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) to update `Table1`:

```
update Table1
set (col1, col2, col100) = (
  select 
    coalesce(t2.col1, Table1.col1),
    coalesce(t2.col2, Table1.col2),
    ................................
    coalesce(t2.col100, Table1.col100)
  from Table2 t2
  where t2.id = Table1.id
)
where exists (select 1 from Table2 t2 where t2.id = Table1.id);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67J1az2g51pG5kLZb3ZUfz/1).
Results:

```
| id    | col1  | col2   | col100 |
| ----- | ----- | ------ | ------ |
| 2346a | apple | green  | WA     |
| d27d7 | pear  | green  | VA     |
| 568ba | lemon | yellow | CA     |
| 9896f | plum  | purple | CA     |
| 1b7da | peach | pink   | GA     |
```